# Azure Performance Data Using Kusto

Tags: azure, kql

I am trying to get some performance data in Azure using Kusto(new to KQL) but running into an issue.  When running the below query it is not giving the computer names that end with APP.  For example we have computers UTDEV01APP15...20, UTDEV01DATA15...20, UTDEV02DMZ01...05.  But when I run the query it is only showing servers from UTDEV01DATA15...20 and UTDEV02DMZ01...05. It doesnt show any of the UTDEV01APP15...20.  I have tried to look up the APP servers using contains == but they still dont come in the results.  I can see all the virtual machines under Workspaces Data Sources>Virtual machines which includes the APP servers.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where (CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName == "_Total") or CounterName == "% Used Memory"
| where (Computer contains "dev")
| project TimeGenerated, CounterName, CounterValue, Computer
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by missing performance counter data. More details could maybe found by querying which counters are sent from each computer.

```
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| summarize array_sort_asc(make_set(CounterName)) by Computer
| sort by Computer
```

The query returns a list of counters for each computer which sends Perf data.